# Arduino Robot: Switch from line-following to bluetooth control?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, arduino, robot

I'm building a prototype robot for a summer camp, and my boss wants it to be a line follower that can then switch to being controlled via bluetooth by an iPhone. My question is, what can I implement in terms of code to make this switch possible? Is there a way I can set a time limit for how long the line following code can run, and after that time limit, have it switch to bluetooth control? Or is there something more effective?

Thanks.

Comment: There is something definitely more effective... A switch! Or otherwise ask your boss how it should be chosen... Or if you don't want a physical switch, just put a button on the iphone app to switch the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The best option than you can implement is probably to always have the robot connected via Bluetooth to the phone, having an option to switch at any time from line follower mode to manual control. This option will offer you the best flexibility.

> Is there a way I can set a time limit for how long the line following
>   code can run

Yes, there are options to do that. The most simplistic way to implement this is using a timer from the robot microcontroller.